# if condition problem with newcommand

Tags: macros, conditionals

Hi all I wrote a simple code at which I created simple variables and some If condition. The output however was not desired

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

%\newcommand{\ReqOpenIssues}{}

\newcommand{\NoOpenIssues}{}

\newcommand{\OpenIssues}[1]{\ifdefined\#1OpenIssues REQ \else \ifdefined\NoOpenIssues NA \fi \fi 
}

\OpenIssues{Req}

\end{document}
```

The desired output is NA
But this is the output:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: `\ifdefined\#` is always true as `\#` is a standard latex command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to build up the macro name using `#1` plus some additional text, you need to use `\ifcsname`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\NoOpenIssues}{}

\newcommand{\OpenIssues}[1]{\ifcsname#1OpenIssues\endcsname
   REQ \else \ifdefined\NoOpenIssues NA \fi \fi 
}

\OpenIssues{Req}

\newcommand{\ReqOpenIssues}{}

\OpenIssues{Req}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [Using \ifdefined on \csname macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231551/using-ifdefined-on-csname-macros)

Comment: Your answer worked! Thanks. However I modified a part of the code that produced an error, here is the modification: \newcommand{\FailedReq}{Nour}
\newcommand{\ReqOpenIssues}{}

\newcommand{\OpenIssues}[1]{\ifcsname#1OpenIssues\endcsname \Failed#1 \else \ifdefined\NoOpenIssues NA \fi \fi 
}
\OpenIssues{Req}